# Is there a list of all municipalities in the USA with population values as a spreadsheet?

Tags: usa, city, population

so I am looking for a list of every municipality in the USA in spreadsheet form, or at least that can be easily imported into a spreadsheet. I would like it to include every municipality type in every state, whether it's a town, township, city, or anything else.

It should also have population values for every municipality, as well as the name and state it's located in. I would like the population values to be estimates from 2016 or later, preferably as recently as possible. Though I would also accept older estimates or 2010 census figures.

I would also prefer if each entry also had a land area, but that is somewhat optional. It is fine if the spreadsheet also contains more information than name, state, population, and area, but it is not necessary.

I did find [this](https://www.uscitieslist.org), but it is paid. I would like to find a free dataset if at all possible, especially because what I'm looking for doesn't quite need to be as extensive as this one is.

So does such a dataset exist? And where can I find it if so?

Comment: you can check https://www.geonames.org/, and especially the files (for example `cities500.zip`) for all cities above a certain population. https://download.geonames.org/export/dump/ https://download.geonames.org/export/dump/readme.txt

Answer (score 1):

This data should be available on [data.census.gov](https://data.census.gov/), specifically by selecting one-year population estimates from the [American Communities Survey](https://www.census.gov/programs-surveys/acs). The geography type that most-closely matches municipalities is the '[place](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Place_(United_States_Census_Bureau))', which includes both incorporated places and Census-designated places, so you'll need to filter the data after downloading. You can read more about the [Census definition of a place on the census.gov website](https://www.census.gov/programs-surveys/geography/about/glossary.html#par_textimage_14). You may also want to check that the Census definition of a place matches your definition of a municipality by dip sampling the data you've downloaded.